# SQL Second latest date Subselect

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, max

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
  MAX (EXPDATE) AS PREVDATE, 
  BUSINESSUNIT AS BUSUNIT, 
  UNIT AS UNITNO
FROM 
  proddta.V_LeaseExpiry_profile
WHERE 
  EXPDATE < (
    (  SELECT 
         MAX (EXPDATE)
       FROM 
         proddta.V_LeaseExpiry_profile
       WHERE 
         TRIM (BUSINESSUNIT) = '33700' AND UNIT = '900')
    )
  AND 
  TRIM (BUSINESSUNIT) = '33700'
  AND 
  UNIT = '900'
GROUP BY 
  BUSINESSUNIT, 
  UNIT
```

Which works fine when I specify the Business Unit and Unit, but when I remove them from the query (i.e. - I want to do this for all units), it no longer grabs the second latest date- it grabs the latest date.

Essentially, I am trying to find each unit's Previous Expiry Date, but there may be duplicate rows, so I need to ensure it is not the same as the MAX ExpDate.

Comment: Are you sure you are using sql server? Trim is not a built in function of sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the second expiry date use `dense_rank()` (or `offset`/`fetch`):

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by businessunit, unit
                                order by EXPDATE desc) as seqnum
      from proddta.V_LeaseExpiry_profile 
     ) p
where seqnum = 2;
```

This returns the appropriate values for all businessunit/unit combinations.  You can use a `where` clause to get just one combo, if that is all you need.

Comment: thanks so much for the quick reply!  when I enter this in my query analyzer, it is telling me the p. is undefined... am I missing something?

Comment: @4bpauly `from proddta.V_LeaseExpiry_profile AS p` or change in subquery `p.*` to `*`

Comment: this worked brilliantly at using the last date.  One more request - I am trying to now group them by Business Unit and Unit, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Any thoughts?